# How to prevent ONE field of one state to be persisted with NgxsStoragePluginModule

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs, web-storage

I've a small issue:
I'm using the NgxsStoragePluginModule to persists my states accross refreshes.

But in my AuthState, I do set the `authError`, if the login wasn't successfull.

One case could be a wrong password, other could be that I've to much trials.

Then, if I refresh the page, I would expect to not have any auth error on this page, the user is not even trying to login.

I've checked the documentation(https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/storage), but they only mention how to exclude from storage one state, but they don't say anything about how to exclude one property of the state.

Here is how I update this authError:

```
  @Action(LoginWithPasswordAction)
  async loginWithPassword(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: LoginWithPasswordAction) {
    ctx.patchState({
      authError: null,
    });
    try {
      await this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.email, action.password);
      await this.router.navigate(['/']);
    } catch (exception) {

      console.log('Login Setting exception to'+exception.message)
      ctx.patchState({
        authError: exception.message,
      });
    }
  }
```

I tried to patch the state with a null error in the ngxsOnInit, but it seems it doesn't work.

I could put this in another state, but since it's "auth" related, I was thinking it was quite logical to have it here.

Does anybody have an idea how to prevent it from being saved? Or at least reset it when I reload?

Comment: You can use a `SerializationInterceptor` for this scenario. You can skip that property while serializing it.

Comment: @Eldar Thank you for the comment, is this something that can be done only for one state?

Comment: The function accepts 2 prameters 1 is object to be serialized and 2 is the key of the state (which you pass to the store config) you can check the key and delete the property that you want to not to serialize.